# yii2 Summernote uploadToS3 returns yii\di\NotInstantiableException

Tags: dependency-injection, yii2, summernote

I'm running https://github.com/marqu3s/yii2-summernote installed via Composer v1.10.26 under Yii2, php v7.4.

I've been struggling to find the problem/solution with S3 uploads. When I click the image button, select a file and click Upload, I get a return of:

```
Exception (Not instantiable) 'yii\di\NotInstantiableException' 
with message 'Failed to instantiate component or class "common\actions\SignAwsRequestAction".'

in ../advanced/_protected/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php:509

Stack trace:
#0 ../advanced/_protected/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(385): yii\di\Container->getDependencies()
#1 ../advanced/_protected/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(170): yii\di\Container->build()
#2 ../advanced/_protected/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(365): yii\di\Container->get()
#3 ../advanced/_protected/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(248): yii\BaseYii::createObject()
#4 ../advanced/_protected/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(147): yii\base\Controller->createAction()
```

Strange this is, I know the first time I set it up, it was working, so something must have changed in the mean time that broke it. It looks like a path problem where it can't find:

> /_protected/vendor/marqu3s/yii2-summernote/actions/SignAwsRequestAction.php

**Any advice or things to try is greatly appreciated and thanks for looking. I did move the vendor directory to "_protected/vendor", but everything else seems to be working fine.**

My controller is properly according to the docs:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'sign-aws-request' => ['POST'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}

public function actions()
{
    return [
        'sign-aws-request' => [
            'class' => 'common\actions\SignAwsRequestAction',
            'clientPrivateKey' => $key,
            'clientPrivateSecret' => $secret,
            'expectedBucketName' => $editor_img_bucket,
            'expectedHostName' => $editor_img_bucket,
            'expectedMaxSize' => '1024000'
        ]
    ];
}
```

Active Form field:

```
echo $form->field($model, 'body')->widget(Summernote::className(), [
    'uploadToS3' => true,
    'signEndpoint' => '/controller/sign-aws-request?v4=true',
    'bucket' => Yii::$app->params['awss3Fs']['editor_img_bucket'],
    'folder' => $path,
    'filenamePrefix' => "",
    'maxFileSize' => 1024000,
    'expiration' => gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.000\Z', strtotime('+5 minutes')),
    'clientOptions' => [
        'toolbar' => \Yii::$app->params['summernote_toolbar'],
        'codeviewFilter' => false,
        'codeviewIframeFilter' => false,
        'codeviewFilterRegex' => 'custom-regex'
    ],
]);
```

Contents of vendor/marqu3s/yii2-summernote/composer.json

```
{
    "name": "marqu3s/yii2-summernote",
    "description": "Yii2 Summernote widget. Super simple WYSIWYG editor on Bootstrap",
    "type": "yii2-extension",
    "keywords": [
        "yii2",
        "summernote",
        "widget",
        "wysiwyg"
    ],
    "homepage": "https://github.com/marqu3s/yii2-summernote",
    "time": "2016-01-15",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Aleksandr Zelenin",
            "email": "aleksandr@zelenin.me",
            "homepage": "http://zelenin.me",
            "role": "Developer"
        },
        {
            "name": "Joao Marques",
            "email": "joao@jjmf.com",
            "role": "Developer"
        }
    ],
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/zelenin/yii2-summernote-widget/issues",
        "source": "https://github.com/marqu3s/yii2-summernote"
    },
    "require": {
        "yiisoft/yii2": "~2",
        "bower-asset/codemirror": "@stable",
        "bower-asset/summernote": "0.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "marqu3s\\summernote\\": ""
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "asset-installer-paths": {
            "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
            "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
        }
    }
}
```

Yii2 main composer.json (config stuff)

```
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "vendor/",
        "process-timeout": 1800,
        "fxp-asset": {
            "enabled": false,
            "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
            "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
        },
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "platform": {
            "php": "7.4.28"
        },
        "allow-plugins": {
            "yiisoft/yii2-composer": true
        }
    },
    "conflict": {
        "bower-asset/fullcalendar": "^4.3.0"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
        }
    ]
```

Thanks for your help.